# How to return a multi select sql query with a few joins in a flat row

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to return a list of user types by postcode area. For example I have a column "membertype" which may be X, Y or Z. In the postcode area G83 I may have multiple type X and multiple type Y. I'm looking to return a result like the following

| postcode | X | Y |

| G83      | 9 | 3 |

Trying this for now

```
SELECT substring(postcode, 1, locate (' ', postcode) - 1) AS postcode, count(u.membertype) AS cook, count(u2.membertype) AS customer FROM user_locations AS ul
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.id = ul.user_id
LEFT JOIN users AS u2 ON u2.id = ul.user_id
WHERE u.membertype = "seller"
OR u2.membertype = "customer"
GROUP BY postcode
```

I'd like a response that I can loop through to output a table in my app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FIELDS TERMINATED BY':

```
SELECT substring(postcode, 1, locate (' ', postcode) - 1) AS postcode, count(u.membertype) AS cook, count(u2.membertype) AS customer FROM user_locations AS ul
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.id = ul.user_id
LEFT JOIN users AS u2 ON u2.id = ul.user_id
WHERE u.membertype = "seller"
OR u2.membertype = "customer"
GROUP BY postcode
INTO OUTFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/files.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Comment: Thankyou, but: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'' at line 7

Comment: I updated the code. Change the path where you wish to save the formatted data.